# When I double click on the separator of TableView in a column Header, the button in the column dissappears

Tags: javafx

When I  double click on the separator of TableView in a column Header, the button in the column disappears. Is there any event that is triggered when that particular part is double clicked and how can I stop it?

Comment: Could you give a few more details?  What have you tried?  Why didn't it work?  And what is the *expected* behavior, that isn't happening?

Comment: When I click on the separator of the column the content in the column disappears only if it is a radio button or a simple button. If there is only text inside that column then nothing happens. Just the width of the column decreases to min Width

Answer (score 1):

Works for me:

```
    TableColumn<AuxTable, AuxTableColString> col = new TableColumn<>();
    col.setSortable(false);
    setCallbackString(col);
    setHeader(text, col);
    //Header not exists yet
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        getTableHeader().setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
            if (event.getClickCount() > 1) {
                //forces render
                col.getTableView().refresh();
            }
        });
    });
```